# How do I cross compile a haskell program on a linux machine with a windows (PE) target?

Tags: linux, windows, haskell, llvm, cross-compiling

I'd like to develop haskell code that will run on windows and interact with windows OS APIs, but I would like to do it on a linux machine.  How do I accomplish this?  I can compile on a windows machine and that works, but not on a linux machine.  Haskell can use a LLVM backend, can't it?  Can I use LLVM to accomplish this? Or work with MinGW somehow?

Comment: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/36200 might be worth following

Answer (score 9):

I tried many possibilities, including GHC on Wine (didn't work for me, despite many notices advertising that it works "out of the box").

For cross compilation, one problem lies in making GHC find your C libraries and DLLs (for windows). Template Haskell will also give you headaches (because it needs to load linux libraries but then compile for windows).

I never managed to get around those problems properly.

In the end, I opted for installing GHC on a Windows VM, and now I use a script to push stuff to a repo, connect to the windows machine via SSH, pull, clean, recompile and test, all executed from a linux CLI and giving me feedback about what's happening on windows.

EDIT: I'm not providing this answer in an attempt to discourage anyone from trying something smarter. I too am interested in real cross-compilation and, if someone has a good solution, I'm all ears. My alternative method always works, but it really is a pain, having to start a VM just for this. Furthermore, it implies using one VM per OS per architecture, which is quite heavy.

Comment: Did you look into MINGW?

Comment: It's been a long time, but I'm still interested in addressing this problem.

Several options come to mind, from wine to ReacOS. It might be worth it to re-evaluate them.

If someone can propose a good solution, it would be greatly appreciated. While I may not have time to craft the solution myself, I should have time to try it if setup is trivial/automated. I'm using this in production, so it would be a small, but decent test case.

Comment: In the years since this, docker and CICD have become far more common and accessible. I imagine it might be possible with a properly set up docker container in GitLab ci for instance